# How can I disable spellchecking of latex math fragments in markdown in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there way to configure any of the spell check plugins in visual studio to ignore math fragments between $$ delimiters in markdown?

```
$$
Δx = \frac{1}{2} (v_i + v_f)  Δt ignore any mi∑takes here
$$

configure to notice this mi∑take

$$
Δx = \frac{1}{2} (v_i + v_f)  Δt 
$$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spellright plug-in with these settings:

```
"spellright.ignoreRegExpsByClass": {
"markdown": [ 
"/\\\\\\\\\\([^]*?\\\\\\\\\\)/gm" ,   
"/\\\\\\\\\\[[^]*?\\\\\\\\\\]/gm" ,
"/\\$\\$[^]*?\\$\\$/gm" ],
]
}
```

How I got there:

1. I moved from git pages to git lab pages so I was using this syntax

```
\( <mathjax> \)
```

because I'm using jekyll to produced pages from markdown, I had to escape those back slashes

```
\\( <mathjax> \\)
```

Then I used spellright plug-ins regex ignore setting.
To ignore anything between the delimiters I had to escape the backslashes in the regex, and because the regex is entered as a string, I had to escape the backslashes in the string so I end up with:

```
"spellright.ignoreRegExpsByClass": {
"markdown": [    
"/\\\\\\\\\\(.*\\\\\\\\\\)/gm" ,   
"/\\\\\\\\\\[.*\\\\\\\\\\]/gm" ]
}
```

but the . wasn't matching new line characters, so I changed this to:

```
"spellright.ignoreRegExpsByClass": {
"markdown": [ 
"/\\\\\\\\\\([^]*?\\\\\\\\\\)/gm" ,   
"/\\\\\\\\\\[[^]*?\\\\\\\\\\]/gm" ,
]
}
```

And added in a pattern to match by original $$...$$ problem

```
"spellright.ignoreRegExpsByClass": {
"markdown": [ 
"/\\\\\\\\\\([^]*?\\\\\\\\\\)/gm" ,   
"/\\\\\\\\\\[[^]*?\\\\\\\\\\]/gm" ,
"/\\$\\$[^]*?\\$\\$/gm" ],
]
}
```